# Expected value of a marginal distribution when the joint distribution is given

Tags: self-study, random-variable, expected-value, joint-distribution

I am asked to find the expected value of a vector of two random variables when the joint density is given. Is the recipe for solving this problem:

- Find the marginal distributions
- Find the expected values of the marginal distributions

which will involve a relatively long integration process, since I have to find the two marginals and then the two expected values?

Or is there some shortcut?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @Xi'an What are the double integrals I should solve? Something like $\int\int xyf(x,y)dxdy$?

Comment: @gung yes; tag added

Comment: The expected value of a _vector_ $(X,Y)$ random variable is defined to be $E(X,Y])= (E[X], E[Y])$, that is, the vector of the individual expectations. So you don't really have a "shortcut" except that you can hide what you are doing in a double integral. $$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\right]\,\mathrm dx =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx,$$ and similarly for $Y$. Is solving the rightmost integral the same as first finding the marginal?

Answer (score 2):

As rightly pointed out by [Dilip Sarwate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/6633/dilip-sarwate), computing the expectation of one component as a two dimensional integral requires integrating out the other element of the vector:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] =   \iint x\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx,$$
(which is a special [case of the so-called law of the uncounscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Joint_distributions)). The only simplifications I can think of is

1. when finding the conditional expectation of one component given the other is easier:
   $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]] =  \int x\,f_{X|Y}(x|y)\,\mathrm dx\,f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy,$$
   by [the double projection theorem](https://patternsofideas.wordpress.com/2016/10/13/conditional-expectation-as-projection/), in the sense that this could require computing a single marginal instead of two;
2. when computing the marginal cdf is easier, since
   $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(x)\,\mathrm dx-\int_{+\infty}^0 (1-F_X(x))\,\mathrm dx$$
   by an [integration by parts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/305035/7224).

Comment: In #1, about the conditional, are there supposed to be *two* $\mathrm dx$ in the expression? Forgive my ignorance, I'm not sure how to understand the expression as it is right now given there's only one integral symbol and two $\mathrm dx$. The link to the reference is broken, and Archive.org's [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170714232257/https://patternsofideas.wordpress.com/2016/10/13/conditional-expectation-as-projection/) doesn't show the LaTeX equations.

Comment: @AhmedFasih: typo corrected

Comment: FYI, 1. is called "The Law of Iterated Expectation" or "Adam's law".

Answer (score -1):

Using Monte Carlo estimate, the expected value for the marginal distribution will the $\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i}{N}$ where $x_i$ are x's samples from the (x,y) samples from joint distribution.

By Monte Carlo integration, $\int\int\phi(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy$ can be estimated by $\frac{1}{N}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N\phi(x_i,y_i)$. Here, we have $\phi(x,y)= x$.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.