# How to calculate expectation of a discrete random variable using CDF?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-function

[image]

Please refere to the attached image (source: Wikipedia). They have derived the formula (summation one) for discrete random variable as a special case. Can anybody please help me understand how to derive that formula from the integral formula? I already have understanding for the integral formula(continuous case).

Comment: Two hints: You have $P(X>n)=1-F(n)$.  If $X$ can only be an integer, then $F(x)=F(n)$ for $n \le x \lt n+1$ so $\int\limits_{x=n}^{n+1} (1-F(x))\, dx = \int\limits_{x=n}^{n+1} (1-F(n))\, dx = 1-F(n)$

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck.

Comment: Summarion by parts, already answred here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305031/expectation-when-cumulative-distribution-function-is-given

Answer (score 0):

[Henry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596836/how-to-calculate-expectation-of-a-discrete-random-variable-using-cdf#comment1104705_596836) has provided rather ingenious hints which OP can use to formally jot down the proof. Unless OP adds anything further regarding their attempt, I am not proceeding on that front.

For broader purpose, here is another take and a commentary.

$\bullet$ Observe

\begin{align}\sum_{n~=~0}^\infty \mathbf P[X >n] &=  \sum_{n~=~1}^\infty \mathbf P[X \geq n]\\ &=\sum_{n~=~1}^\infty \left\{ \sum_{x~=~n}^\infty\mathbf P[X = x] \right\}\\ &= \sum_{x~=~1}^\infty \left\{ \sum_{n~=~1}^x\mathbf P[X = x] \right\}~~~~~~~~~\because\textrm{(Fubini's Theorem)}\\ &= \sum_{x~=~1}^\infty \left\{\mathbf P[X = x] \sum_{n~=~1}^x1\right\}; \tag 1\label 1\end{align}

from $\eqref 1$ the rest follows.

$\bullet$ If $X$ is only a non-negative random variable, then

\begin{align}\sum_{n~=~1}^\infty \mathbf P[X \geq n] & = \sum_{n~=~1}^\infty \left\{ \mathbf P[n \leq X < n+1] + \mathbf P[n+1 \leq X < n+2]+ \ldots\right\}\\ &=\sum_{\ell~=~1}^\infty \ell\times \mathbf P[\underbrace{\ell \leq X < \ell+1}_{\lfloor X\rfloor ~=~ \ell}]\\ &= \mathbb E\lfloor X\rfloor.\tag 2\end{align}

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory, *Jeffrey S. Rosenthal,* World Scientific Publishing,  $2006,$ sec. $4.3,$ p. $49.$